# How can I implement the linked list in VHDL?

Tags: linked-list, vhdl

Is it possible to create linked lists in VHDL? 
(ex. read the file at zero time and load all the values into it?)

Comment: Are you talking about for simulation, or synthesis?

Comment: Yes. Google "VHDL access type example". It's not synthesisable. I'm not sure a linked list ever could be - not practically, anyway.

Comment: Synthesis I mean but the simulation can helpfull by itself.

Comment: As @MatthewTaylor says: maybe you could synthesize a linked list but as the data has to be know at compile time you would end up with a static list. You could walk past the items but there is no way to add, remove or re-order items.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. Not only as an static list as mentioned in the comments but also dynamic. 
My solution would go along the lines of using a RAM (most likely Block RAM, but this is really architecture depended) and storing there the required data along with a pointer to the next item and a valid bit (optional) and "last" flag. It would look something like:

```
                     RAM 
  Addr0   -> | Valid0 & Last0 & Data0 & Pointer0 |
  Addr1   -> | Valid1 & Last1 & Data1 & Pointer1 |
               ...
  AddrN   -> | ValidN & LastN & DataN & PointerN |
```

So, for example, after initialization, assuming some random data and that the linked list have been loaded in order with N values (and a not circular list), it may look like:

```
                        RAM 
                        V   L   Data     Pointer
  Addr0(0000000)   -> | 1 & 0 & XXXXXX & 0000001 |
  Addr1(0000001)   -> | 1 & 0 & YYYYYY & 0000010 |
                       ...
  AddrN(xxxxxx0)   -> | 1 & 1 & ZZZZZZ & 0000000 |
```

After this, the contents of the RAM can be altered as required. For example, to "delete" element 1 ( in addr = Addr1), the Pointer0 and Valid1 should be changed:

```
                        RAM 
                        V   L   Data     Pointer
  Addr0(0000000)   -> | 1 & 0 & XXXXXX & 0000010 |
  Addr1(0000001)   -> | 0 & 0 & YYYYYY & 0000010 |
  Addr1(0000010)   -> | 1 & 0 & MMMMMM & 0000011 |
               ...
  AddrN(xxxxxx0)   -> | 1 & 1 & ZZZZZZ & 0000000 |
```

Or adding an element between element0 and element1:

```
                        RAM 
                        V   L   Data     Pointer
  Addr0(0000000)   -> | 1 & 0 & XXXXXX & xxxxxx1 |
  Addr1(0000001)   -> | 1 & 0 & YYYYYY & 0000010 |
  Addr1(0000010)   -> | 1 & 0 & MMMMMM & 0000011 |
               ...
  AddrN(xxxxxx0)   -> | 1 & 1 & ZZZZZZ & 0000000 |
  AddrN(xxxxxx1)   -> | 1 & 0 & ZZZZZZ & 0000001 |
```

Again, this is only an idea and several improvements could be made. One of such would be to use record types instead of concatenating for ease of use ( you would have to transform it to a normal std_logic_vector if you are using a block Ram, but this is architecture depended).

Good Luck!